# Can Lightroom & Elements on different PCs share the same photos?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop-elements, sharing

I use Lightroom for my management & editing etc & love it, however my wife needs to access the same pictures via a separate laptop, preferably via Elements or ACDSee.

I can copy my folders to a network drive with no problem & the laptop can access them from there, but would Elements be able to use the keywords created in Lightroom? If so how?
Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: We have two previous questions that basically answer this already, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/can-lightroom-and-photoshop-elements-share-catalog-info and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/how-to-use-lightroom-and-photoshop-elements-together If you have further questions, feel free to come back here and edit this question to update it with the detail of what you are stuck on!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.elementsvillage.com/forums/showthread.php?t=64642) helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set up a network share on the computer where the pictures are being shared, with that said.

lightroom will see the PSDs that the elements would create but not the edits and elements will not see any changes that lightroom as completed as they both use different databases for their catalogs and elements cant see the "changes" database that lightroom uses. for that matter, windows can not see the "changes" database.

so in once sense, for sharing the same files, this is doable; for sharing edits, not likely.